# Is this a special case of the de Finetti theorem?

Tags: probability-distributions, permutations, representation-theory, information-theory, bayesian

I am looking at a problem in information theory and I have a result that concerns $n$-bit strings of some finite alphabet for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I have a distribution $p_{X^n}$ which is some probability distribution over all $n$-bit strings. $p_{X^n}$ is the optimal input distribution to achieve the one-shot capacity of $n$ i.i.d. copies of some channel $W_{Y|X}$ i.e. the one-shot capacity of $W^{\otimes n}_{Y|X}$. $p_{X^n}$ is therefore invariant under any permutation of the $n$ positions. For example, if we consider $n=3$ i.e. $3$-bit strings, I have that $p_{x_1x_2x_3} = p_{x_1x_3x_2} = p_{x_2x_1x_3} = p_{x_2x_3x_1} = p_{x_3x_2x_1} = p_{x_3x_1x_2}$. As we increase $n$, we add more copies of $W_{Y|X}$. Hence, the permutation invariance of our capacity-achieving $p_{X^n}$ holds for any choice of $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Let us consider i.i.d. distributions $q_{X^k}^i = \prod\limits_{j=1}^kq^i_{X_j}$ for any choice of distribution $q^i$ on the alphabet. Does there always exist a convex combination of such i.i.d. distributions such that

$$p_{X^k} = \sum_{i}\mu(i)q_{X^k}^i$$

where $\mu(i)$ is some measure that assigns a weight to each element of our convex combination. Is this a claim that follows from the de Finetti theorem (in particular, Theorem 2 of [these notes](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejordan/courses/260-spring10/lectures/lecture1.pdf))? The point that I am confused about is whether my $p_{X^k}$ can be thought of as extendible for $n>k$ to allow me to invoke the de Finetti theorem.

Comment: What do you mean by "support only on permutation invariant strings"? Since you're linking to de Finetti stuff, do you just mean that $X_1^n$ is an exchangable sequence? If so, then this famously doesn't work for finite sequences: see the first page of _Diaconis, Persi, and David Freedman. "Finite exchangeable sequences." The Annals of Probability (1980): 745-764._ for a classic counterexample (the paper is mostly about how close one can get to a de Finetti type result for finite sequences).

Comment: @stochasticboy321, many thanks for the references and comment. It helped me understand and reword the question. I have clarified the question about exchangeability (yes, your statement is what I meant). I did not realize that the de Finetti result does not apply in the finite $n$ case. In my case, $p_{X^n}$ is a distribution that achieves the one-shot capacity of $n$ iid copies of some channel $W_{Y|X}$. So for every $n$, I obtain a $p_{X^n}$ that satifies the exchangeability condition. I'm not sure if this is enough for me to use the de Finetti theorems...

Comment: Ah interesting. If we have this for each $n$, then in fact we can use the results of Diaconis and Freedman to argue this. They show that if you have an exchangable sequence of $n$ random variables, then for any $k \le n$, the best mixture-of-iid approximation of the law of $P_{X^k}$ has distance at most $O(k/n)$ from $P_{X^k}$. So now take any $m \gg n,$ and consider the law of $P_{X^n}$. Since $P_{X^m}$ is exchangable, we can construct a mixtrue-of-iid approximation to $P_{X^n}$ with total variation distance of $O(n/m),$ and taking the limit as $m \to \infty$

Comment: (contd.) shows us that for every $n$, there exists some prior $\pi$ on the set of laws on the given finite element such that $P_{X^n}(\cdot) = \int q^{\otimes n}(\cdot) \pi(\mathrm{d}q)$. I guess in your question you want a little bit more, that $\pi$ is supported on a countable number of laws. This is not obvious to me, but I don't think that in general we get a countable mixture even via de Finetti, so I would suspect not.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 thank you for the comment. I don't need it to be a finite sum, it can be an integral so that's not an issue. To clarify why Diaconis-Freedman applies here - For each $n$, I have a set of strings $X^n$ and I know that $p_{X^n}$ on this set is invariant under permutations of the $n$ positions. Let $k\ll n$. The $p_{X^k}$ I have is some invariant distribution under permutations of the $k$ positions. But don't I need $p_{X^k}$ to be the marginal distribution of $p_{X^n}$ in order to apply the results of Diaconis and Freedman? I don't see why that last condition holds in my case.